# google analytics apis not working in production

Tags: google-analytics

I am trying to use the google analytics apis v3 to embed the analytics graph to my website using Certificate file.  I got it to work on the local machine but when I deploy the code to my web server it produces this error:

The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

Does anyone know what is causing this error message and why I can't get the google graph on my production website?

Here is the code that is working on my local machine:

```
string scope = AnalyticsService.Scopes.AnalyticsReadonly.GetStringValue(),
                   x509Certificate2File = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/privatekey.p12"),
                   x509Certificate2FilePassword = "notasecret",
                   serviceAccountId = "xxxxxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com",
                   profileId = "ga:xxxxxxxx",
                startDate = "2013-10-06",
           endDate = "2013-11-07";

            AuthorizationServerDescription desc = GoogleAuthenticationServer.Description;

            X509Certificate2 key = new X509Certificate2(x509Certificate2File, x509Certificate2FilePassword, X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

            AssertionFlowClient client = new AssertionFlowClient(desc, key) { ServiceAccountId = serviceAccountId, Scope = scope };

            OAuth2Authenticator<AssertionFlowClient> auth = new OAuth2Authenticator<AssertionFlowClient>(client, AssertionFlowClient.GetState);

            AnalyticsService gas = new AnalyticsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer() { Authenticator = auth });

    DataResource.GaResource.GetRequest request = gas.Data.Ga.Get(profileId, startDate, endDate, "ga:visits");

    request.Dimensions = "ga:day";
    request.MaxResults = 10;

    /* error 400 occur here on the production */
    Google.Apis.Analytics.v3.Data.GaData data = request.Execute();
```

Thanks

Comment: Is you production server in a different time zone?  If so this could mess up the signature.

Comment: the production is in the same time zone where i live

Answer (score 0):

There is only one possibility and without looking at the code you're going to have to chase it down; one of the paths are wrong and needs to be changed. This could be in the form of an IP address as well when I say "path" as you are calling something that is not there. It worked fine on your local machine (correct path) and it gave a 400 on the remote one (bad request) as in calling the wrong place.

Comment: It read the certificate file and continue to run until it execute the code "Google.Apis.Analytics.v3.Data.GaData data = request.Execute();" that where error 400 occur.

here is the code.

string startDate = "2013-11-06",
           endDate = "2013-11-07",
    profileId = "ga:xxxxxxxx";

    DataResource.GaResource.GetRequest request = gaAuth.GAS.Data.Ga.Get(profileId , startDate, endDate, "ga:visitors");

    request.Dimensions = "ga:visitorType";

/* error 400 at this line */
    Google.Apis.Analytics.v3.Data.GaData data = request.Execute();